How to sort an array with dropdown menu while only showing 10 results per page?
I'm creating a search result page, and I'm trying to sort/filter the results using a dropdown menu. However, I also want for my code to still only show 10 results per page. I tried sorting results using an if statement, but I have no idea how to actually sort the results on the page.
There's more code than listed, but I got rid of some unnecessary things so I can be more clear about my problem. The result array include objects that have a name, description, website, categories, upvotes, and downvotes. The code below only includes the name.
Basically, I want the results to be sorted and only 10 results to show up on the page at a time. How do I do that?


//imports


const results = [...]

export default function SearchResults() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0); 

    const List = () => {
        return (
            <>
            {
                results.slice(page * 10, page * 10 + 10).map((result) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="bg-gray-800 shadow-lg shadow-red-500 m-5">
                            <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 p-5">
                                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-4">
                                        <p className="text-lg font-bold">{result.name}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
            </>
        )
    }

    const prevPage = () => {...}

    const nextPage = () => {...}

    const arrangeResults = () => {
        if (orderResults?.value === "A-Z") {
            results.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        } else if (orderResults?.value === "Z-A") {
            results.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
        } else if (orderResults?.value === "Popular") {
            results.sort((a, b) => b.upvotes - a.upvotes);
        } else if (orderResults?.value === "New") {
            // Add functiionality for newest results
        }
    }

    const orderResults = window.document.getElementById("order-results") as HTMLSelectElement;
    orderResults?.addEventListener("change", arrangeResults);

    const PaginationNumbers = () => {...}

    const NOP = () => {...}

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <div>
                <Search/>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                <div className="w-1/2">
                    <List/>
                </div>
                <div className="w-1/3 m-2 p-2 flex flex-col h-fit items-center bg-gray-800">
                    <select name="order-results" id="order-results" className="bg-gray-900 text-white text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                        <option value="A-Z" selected>A-Z</option>
                        <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
                        <option value="Popular">Popular</option>
                        <option value="New">New</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center flex-wrap w-2/3">
                <button onClick={prevPage} className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg">Prev</button>
                <PaginationNumbers/>
                <button onClick={nextPage} className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}



